# How can I publish to a MQTT topic in a Amazon AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, publish, mqtt

I would like to have an easy command like I use in the bash to publish something to a topic on MQTT inside a AWS Lambda function. Along the lines of:
mosquitto_pub -h my.server.com -t "light/set" -m "on"

Background: I would like to turn a lamp on and off with Alexa. Alexa can start a Lambda function, and inside of this Lambda function I would like to start an MQTT publish, because the lamp can listen to a MQTT topic and react on the messages there.(Maybe there are easier solutions, but we are in a complicated (university) network which makes many other approaches more difficult)

Comment: Please accept one of the answers below so that others can know which one you find useful.

Answer (score 49):

If you are using Python, I was able to get an AWS Lambda function to publish a message to AWS IoT using the following inside my handler function:

```py
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('iot-data', region_name='us-east-1')

# Change topic, qos and payload
response = client.publish(
        topic='$aws/things/pi/shadow/update',
        qos=1,
        payload=json.dumps({"foo":"bar"})
    )
```

You will also need to ensure that the Role (in your Lambda function configuration) has a policy attached to allow access to IoT publish function.  Under IAM -> Roles you can add an inline policy to your Lambda function Role like:

```json
{
   "Version": "2016-6-25",
   "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iot:Publish"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Roy.
In the end we used Ponte, got out of the AWS lambda with an http request that was sent to ponte which then transferred it to mqtt and sent that to the lamp.

Comment: @xtra that was my question also, in JavaScript it is annoying that we need the endpoint, while in Python not. Have you figured out how to do that in JS without passing the endpoint?

Answer (score 13):

If you're using Node.js, this will work -

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({ endpoint: '*****************.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' });

exports.handler = async(event) => {
  console.log("Event => " + JSON.stringify(event));
  var params = {
      topic: "MyTopic",
      payload: JSON.stringify(event),
      qos: 0
  };
    
  return iotdata.publish(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
          console.log("ERROR => " + JSON.stringify(err));
      } else {
          console.log("Success");
      }
  }).promise();
};
```

Remember to add iot:publish permission to the role used by this lambda function.

Comment: Why do we need to specify the endpoint in JS, but in python we can simply only pass the region?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin we can have multiple endpoints in the same region.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that, I need to check how is this possible. Or could you please show how could this be possible? Or what is the key-word to search for? because I could not find this in a quick search. But apparently Python boto3 is possible to get the "default" endpoint without specifying it?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin I don't have any experience with Python boto3, so won't be able to help with that.

Answer (score 8):

The AWS SDK has two classes to work with IoT: Iot and IotData. [IotData.publish](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IotData.html#publish-property) is the method you are looking for. It looks like the Iot object is for working with things and IotData is for working with MQTT and shadows. This ought to be directly referenced in the documentation on MQTT and shadows, but it isn't.

This service (IotData) is also available [in the CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot-data/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It got me on the right track with publishing an event from bash: `aws iot-data publish --cli-input-json '{"topic":"myTopic", "qos": 0, "payload": "{\"myKey\": 54321, \"myOtherKey\": 12345"}'`. Payload's keys have to be in double quotes and escaped with backslashes.

Answer (score 3):

The previous post about nodeJS send the message 2 times for me.
Correction is here

```
    var mqttParams = {
        topic: topicName,
        payload: JSON.stringify(event),
        qos: 1
    };
    
    const request = iotdata.publish(mqttParams);
    request
        .on('success', () => console.log("Success"))
        .on('error', () => console.log("Error"))
    return new Promise(() => request.send());
```

Comment: Legend. I was struggling with the double message thing.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me using Rust.

main.rs:

```
use lambda_http::aws_lambda_events::serde_json;
use lambda_runtime::{service_fn, Error, LambdaEvent};
use serde_json::Value;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let func = service_fn(func);
    lambda_runtime::run(func).await?;
    Ok(())
}

async fn func(_event: LambdaEvent<Value>) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let config = aws_config::load_from_env().await;
    let client = aws_sdk_iotdataplane::Client::new(&config);
    let publish = client
        .publish()
        .topic("topic")
        .qos(1)
        .payload(aws_smithy_types::Blob::new("payload"));
    publish.send().await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "MyLambda"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
lambda_http = { version = "0.7", default-features = false, features = ["apigw_http"] }
lambda_runtime = "0.7"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["macros"] }
aws-config = "0.51.0"
aws-sdk-iotdataplane = "0.21.0"
aws-smithy-types = "0.51.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Node.js, you need to install the mqtt library. The following steps help you download and install mqtt library on AWS Lambda.

1. [Download and install Node.js and npm](https://npmjs.com/get-npm) on your PC.
2. [Download MQTT library for node.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js).
3. Unzip it at the nodejs directory that Node.js was installed. (In Windows 10 x64, nodejs directory is `C:\Program Files\nodejs`)
4. Create a folder to store the mqtt installed files. For example, `D:\lambda_function`.
5. Run Command Prompt as administrator, change directory to nodejs directory.
6. Install mqtt library to `D:\lambda_function`.

   ```
   C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install --prefix "D:\lambda_function” mqtt
   ```

[Here's a similar project](https://www.hackster.io/phpoc_man/amazon-echo-control-diy-iot-devices-with-phpoc-037b11).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple JavaScript code using `async` `await`:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = async event => {
  try {
    const iotData = new AWS.IotData({ endpoint: "IOT_SERVICE_ID-ats.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com" });

    const params = {
      topic: 'some/topic',
      payload: JSON.stringify({ var1: "val1" })
    }

    result = await iotData.publish(params).promise();

    console.log(result);

    return { statusCode: 200, body: `IoT message published.` };
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return { statusCode: 500, body: `IoT message could not be published.` };
  }
};
```

Don't forget to give this lambda the required *iot:publish* permission to publish to this IoT topic.