# How to set a profile on an aws client

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-iot

I'm trying to create an AWS client for IOT following this article: [How can I publish to a MQTT topic in a Amazon AWS Lambda function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810289/how-can-i-publish-to-a-mqtt-topic-in-a-amazon-aws-lambda-function)

```
client = boto3.client('iot-data', region_name='us-east-1')
```

However I need to set a profile so that `boto3` picks the correct credentials from my `~/.aws/credentials` file.

The articles that describe how to do this ([How to choose an AWS profile when using boto3 to connect to CloudFront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378422/how-to-choose-an-aws-profile-when-using-boto3-to-connect-to-cloudfront)) use `Session` instead of creating a `client`. However `iot-data` is not a "resource" that you can get from Session.

```
boto_session = boto3.Session(profile_name='my-profile')
boto_client = boto_session.resource('iot-data', region_name='us-west-1')
```

When I try the above I get the error:

```
Consider using a boto3.client('iot-data') instead of a resource for 'iot-data'
```

And we've achieved full catch-22 status. How can I get an appropriate IOT client using an AWS profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IoTDataPlane](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iot-data.html) does **not have resource**. You can only use `client` with the IoTDataPlane:

```
boto_session.client('iot-data', region_name='us-west-1')
```

Comment: But how do I configure what profile to use? `profile_name` is not an option on client.

Comment: @DavidParks Your `boto_session` will have the profile set.